# Plotting factorial of x function in gnuplot?

Tags: graph, plot, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot the *`x!`* function in gnuplot, I defined first the factorial function and then called it, but I'm always getting stack overflow, no matter what bounds I set to the graph.

This what I've tried:

```
gnuplot>  fac(n) = (n==0) ? 1 : n * fac(n-1)  
gnuplot> plot [0:10][0:10] log(fac(x)), log(x**x)  
stack overflow
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I should define the fac function to be integer. Otherwise, when plotting all along the x-axis, it'll evaluate a long range of real numbers, a huge one actually, which will always cause the overflow.

So, the function should be defined:

```
fac(x) = (int(x)==0) ? 1.0 : int(x) * fac(int(x)-1.0)
```

Comment: Right, and the faculty function is defined for integers only, so you could add an appropriate sampling x-range: `set samples 11` (for the xrange `[0:10]`).

Answer (score 13):

Another soultion would be to use the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) (intrinsic function in gnuplot).

> N!=gamma(N+1)

```
gnuplot> plot [0:10][0:10] log(gamma(x+1)), log(x**x)
```